# PrimeNg p-table lazyLoadOnInit doesn't work

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

The **[lazyLoadOnInit]** input of the **p-table**, when set to *false*, doesn't work. It still triggers the load event on the initial load. I am using the latest version.

Here is the example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablevirtualscroll-demo-cm3dao?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Does someone know what might be the problem?

Comment: I know this is an old issue, but I'm facing the same problem - did you ever get this resolved and if yes, would be so kind to post the solution?